# C++ link-time dependecies in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a C++ solution in Visual Studio which contains 5 projects(A,B,C,D,E). A, B, C are libraries and D, E are executables. B is dependent on A, C on B and D, E are dependent on C. Compilation sometimes takes a long time and that happens only for the reason that source files of projects don't get compiled at same time, Visual Studio allows for project dependency so no .lib file is missing when linking other projects but there are at most 2 projects compiling at same time, while the only dependency is actually just at link-time.

Is it possible to compile all 5 project's source files in parallel at same time while they would wait for each other just on link-time?

Comment: Not sure about VS's native build system, but this is possible if you use a separate build system like CMake.

Comment: did you enable parallel compilation in MSVC?

Comment: Does your one library depend on other libraries, such as A depend on B? It should be 3 parallel builds.

Comment: @phuclv it is enabled, when I remove dependencies all 5 projects get compiled at once but ofc i get errors when linking

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT there can't be 3 parallel builds because these project dependencies are "chained" only D and E get paralleled because they don't rely on each other, just on previous libraries, like A -> B -> C -> D + E

Comment: By "library" do you mean A, B, C produce DLLs or static libraries?  Static libraries don't *have* a link phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in Visual Studio.

> PreLinkEvent  This event executes before the link step begins.

1. You need to remove all project dependencies.
2. Set maximum parallel builds to 5. (Default is 4)
3. There is a pre-link event in project's properties.

You need to write a PowerShell script to check the existence of related lib/DLL files within a period of time (such as 5 seconds) and call the PowerShell from the command line in Pre-link event.

Comment: This is non-intuitive and fragile.  The dependency system can do this better.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with using PreLinkEvent is that it may deadlock if the number of parallel builds is set too low or error if the computer load factor increases and builds take longer.

Instead, you need to set dependencies at a finer granularity.

1. Split project D into D_objects and D_executable.
2. All the source files will be in D_objects (project type: static library).  It has no dependencies on any project.
3. The linking will take place in D_executable.  It has no source files and depends on A, B, C just as before, and also on D_objects.
4. On the project dependency to D_objects, turn on the "Link Dependency Inputs", so that all the individual compilation units are directly listed on the link command line and you don't get the reference-counting behavior associated with linking a .lib.

Do the same with E.

If B is a static library, it doesn't need to depend on project A.  If it is a DLL, split it the same way as project D.

Do the same with C, so that C_objects has no dependency on A or B.

The build can now do all compilation in parallel.